# Android splash screen size, compatibility with smartphone and tablet, doubts

Tags: android, compatibility, tablet, splash-screen, smartphone

I'm developing an application for Android, but I have some doubts ...

1)I tried to find answer by searching on google and on Stack Overflow, unfortunately I have only found confusing answers, what are the correct size for the splash screen (smartphone/tablet)?

2)To have a 100% compatibility both on smartphones and on tablets I must create two separate applications or just one of them? If i need only one, how i can adapt all to different screens?

3)There is the possibility to avoid that an application can not be installed on certain devices?

Comment: It is better to keep separate splash screens for phone and tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to separate screen for all drawable folder like
ex :for phone only

```
drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi
```

ex:for tablet

```
drawable-large,drawable-small,drawable-normal,drawable-xlarge
```

no need to create two separate application.just create drawable folder

i hope its useful to you.

Comment: you don't need to create different layout file.just only create drawable folder for splash screen solution.

Comment: So i must create two different folder like -phone and -tablet

Obviusly in phone folder i must insert smartphone image with their size, and in tablet i must insert tablet image.

But what are the correct image size of smartphone and tablet, for example for splash screen ??

(p.s. sorry for edit)

Comment: yes you must create only drawable folder not layout or whole app

Comment: what are the correct image size of smartphone and tablet, for example for splash screen ??